# Non-read-only custom fields appear as read-only in profiles

Tags: custom-fields, profile

We have been seeing custom fields added to a profile, though not set to read-only, appearing as read-only in the profile preview. Clearing the cache temporarily cures the problem, but it recurs later. Any suggestions?

We are seeing this in CiviCRM 5.56.0 and 5.55.2 under Drupal 9.

Comment: The issue is still with us in 5.56.1. I suspect a corrupt cache, since if I comment out lines 733 and 744, i.e. removing an if statement in <drupal root>/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php, the problem goes away.

Comment: On further research, it seems sensible to check if there are any custom fields in the cache that purports to contain them, and if there aren't, to recreate the cache.